# jQuery scroll to anchor on click, error in the javascript "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

here's my code, I would appreciate anyones help.

I get an error message of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

when I click on an anchor :C  I don't really understand why, because all the other jQuery bits work.

Javascript:

```js
$(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    if (this.hash) {
      alert(this.hash);
      $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: jQuery(this.hash).offset().top()},2000);
      return false;
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  var  mn = $(".nav");
  hdr = $(".nav").height();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if( wScroll > hdr-20) {
      mn.addClass("navScroll");
    } else {
      mn.removeClass("navScroll");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's seems that the particular has no fit element like `# + location.hash`.

Comment: thanks, but how would i fix it?

Comment: If your "broken" hash is `#about` for example, apparently you have no element with id `about`.

Comment: Thats weird, in my html, there is #1, #2 and #3 ids attached to different anchors.  and when i console.log(this.hash); on the click of an anchor, it shows #1 #2 and #3 :/

Comment: What do you see in the alert `alert(this.hash);` before the error thrown?

Comment: when i click the anchor, it says #1 when the $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: jQuery(this.hash).offset().top()},2000); is hashed out

Comment: Are you sure you have only **1** element with id `1`?!

Comment: It's weird.. Do you have a public URL of this? or can you create a bin? So I could try to debug it..

Comment: no sorry, but would you like the code?

Comment: The code looks fine. But I can't figure it out. Try to upload your project to the web so I could debug it. With your code, if the `hash` is empty (root URL like yourdomain.com) this error will thrown.